# How to preserve view controller variable state in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

My requirement is like hide and show the viewcontroller, when the viewcontroller would be hidden then a small view would be shown at the bottom for all the view controllers, as soon as the the user will click on it the hidden viewcontroller would be shown again. To achieve this I am pushing and poping the view controller each time but I am lossing the previous state of the view controller as I am poping it. So how can I hide the view controller with it's current state?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into databases? CoreData? Serialising your data to JSON and writing it to a file? Hundreds of articles and tutorials on all of them

Comment: Read this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html